# In Grid selenium, do I need to start Hub?

Tags: java, selenium-grid

Accidentally, I start using the node without starting the Hub.. and it is work... flawlessly, with IE, Firefox & chrome.

I'm new for Selenium Grid, so I'm not sure if it is OK or not and if there are any drop back?

using : Selenium 2.45, Java

Comment: What do you mean with "and it is work"? Your won't be able to manage node and route tests to it without hub.

Comment: Yes, I do. I'm able to connect to it directly without starting hub.. and I using it without any problems

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's possible and will work fine as I understand. This option is used for investigating problems with configuration. You can find section [Hub diagnostic messages](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2). It recommends to connect directly to node if 'CREATIONFAILED' message is shown in hub log.